# Indicating year when writing currency

Tags: orthography, numbers

**Is there a convention for indicating the year of a monetary amount?**

Because of inflation citing a monetary sum is rather useless without specifying the year: $20 in 1900 is very different than $20 in 2000.

Is there a standard way to indicate years?

I would expect one of the following, but I haven't found anything to back one up

- **$20 (2000)** but this could be confusing in disciplines that use years when citing sources.
- **2000$20 or 20 2000$** after currency conventions like US$, but these could easily confuse the reader into thinking 2000 is a sum, not a year.
- **$20 (in 2000 dollars)** is perhaps more clear, but is a bit redundant with the two mentions of dollar, and still isn't that clear because it could be interpreted as some kind of fraction ($20 per $2000).

This may be especially useful for charts when indicating axis units.

Comment: In what way is discussing inflation possible without the year? Since inflation is a change over time. How would I buy 1900 bread with y2k dollars?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Not sure I understand your comment. I agree that the year is necessary—just want to know how to indicate it.

Comment: The point is the specie is almost immaterial, better to pick a single data-point (either the amount relative to a fixed point, or the fixed amount).

Comment: I think this question is relevant.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That makes sense. Would still like to know how to indicate that year, even if it stays constant. Especially helpful on charts.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standardized way to indicate this in general

There are concepts such as real value and time value etc but outside of a technical context they must be explicitly indicated

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of charts or graphs it is fairly common to see "*all dollar values converted to xxxx dollars*" or a single mention of the constant value in the accompanying text.